# How to separate upload for 4 different form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an upload form here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3rxpgsja/28/

Upload is working for the first field. But the user needs to upload 4 separate pictures.

```
   <h1> Field One </h1>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
        <br>
        <img id="form-pic-1" src="http://i.imgur.com/zAyt4lX.jpg" alt="your image" height="100" />
    </form>
      <h1> Field Two </h1>
        <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <input type='file' id="imgInp2" />
        <br>
        <img id="form-pic-2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Spider-Firework-Omiya-Japan.jpg/220px-Spider-Firework-Omiya-Japan.jpg" alt="your image" height="100" />
    </form>
```

I added extra JS code for the different fields:

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#form-pic-1').attr('src', e.target.result);
            };

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#form-pic-2').attr('src', e.target.result);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }


      $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });

       $("#imgInp2").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

But so far only the first picture registers a change. The second upload form registers the name of the uploaded pic, but won't display a thumbnail

Comment: Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ouygnj5/11/, thanks to Rory Mcrossan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you have multiple elements in the DOM with the same `id` attribute, which is invalid. They *must* be unique.

To solve the issue, change the elements to use a common class. You can then use a single event handler on all of them. You should also use DOM traversal to find the `.form-pic` that's related to the changed file input. Try this:

```js
$(".imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});

function readURL(input) {
  var $formPic = $(input).siblings('img');
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $formPic.attr('src', e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Field One</h1>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <input type="file" class="imgInp" /><br />
  <img class="form-pic" src="http://i.imgur.com/zAyt4lX.jpg" alt="your image" height="100" />
</form>

<h1>Field Two</h1>
<form id="form2" runat="server">
  <input type="file" class="imgInp" /><br />
  <img class="form-pic" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Spider-Firework-Omiya-Japan.jpg/220px-Spider-Firework-Omiya-Japan.jpg" alt="your image" height="100" />
</form>
```

Comment: I made form-pic-1/form-pic-2 unique. And imgInp/imgInp2 unique. But I knew it was not the best way. Thanks. I'll try that now.

Comment: The updated fiddle still doesn't work, so your points are valid.

Comment: Apologies, you need to use `siblings()`, not `next()`. I put a working snippet in the answer

Comment: That works, cheers. I'll accept this answer and post a working fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

In This example i did for 2 images preview rest of them you can do.

HTML CODE

```
<h1>USER NEEDS 4 SEPARATE UPLOAD FIELDS</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
       <h1> Field One </h1>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
        <br>
        <img id="form-pic-1" src="http://i.imgur.com/zAyt4lX.jpg" alt="your image" height="100" />
    </form>
      <h1> Field Two </h1>
        <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <input type='file' id="imgInp2" />
        <br>
        <img id="form-pic-2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Spider-Firework-Omiya-Japan.jpg/220px-Spider-Firework-Omiya-Japan.jpg" alt="your image" height="100" />
    </form>
```

JS CODE

```
function readURL(input,image_tag_id) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            console.log(image_tag_id);
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#'+image_tag_id).attr('src', e.target.result);
            };


            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }


      $("#imgInp").change(function(){

        readURL(this,'form-pic-1');
    });

       $("#imgInp2").change(function(){

        readURL(this,'form-pic-2');
    });
```

Comment: I was just going through this. Someone else posted a working snippet, so I accepted that. Your solution is elegant. Cheers.

Comment: ya thanks for your upvote. and @Rory his answer smart and sort so please follow that